# Mysql / php Merging UPDATE mysql queries for optimization possible?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to combine these or do I have do separate queries every time? I tried UNION or the AND keyword but I am not getting any results.

I would appreciate some feedback.

```
        $query= "UPDATE sys 
                 SET nice = nice - 1";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        $query= "UPDATE voting_system 
                 SET ugly = ugly + 1";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        $query= "UPDATE voting_check 
                 SET voted = 'ugly'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Comment: They are on three different tables, updating all the rows, so you might as well use three different queries.  You can wrap them in a single transaction if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can separate by comma the tables that you want to update, and then in the SETs append the table name before the row name:

```
 "UPDATE sys, voting_system, voting_check SET sys.nice = sys.nice - 1, voting_system.ugly = voting_system.ugly + 1, voting_check.voted = 'ugly'"
```

Comment: Does it also work if I want to combine update and inserts?

Answer (score 0):

But the truth is MySQL doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement. Oracle does it.

I tried the following update query in a MyQSL server and it worked:

```
UPDATE user, company, event SET user.join_date = NOW(), company.created_at = NOW(), event.created_at = NOW();
```

But when I tried the insert version of the above query it didn't work. Following is the insert version of it.

```
INSERT INTO user, company, event SET user.join_date = NOW(), company.created_at = NOW(), event.created_at = NOW();
```